# React Native Realm DB - Embedded Objects not working for me

Tags: react-native, realm

Working on React Native Realm database ("realm": "11.0.0"), I can't make Embedded Objects documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/realm-database/schemas/embedded-objects/) work.

The error I have is :

```
 ERROR  Exception in HostFunction: Embedded objects cannot be created directly.
```

Please find below the code you can copy/past to reproduce the problem if you like. If you uncomment "embedded: true", this one-to-many relationship example works.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Realm from "realm";

export class Project extends Realm.Object<Project> {
  public _id: number;
  public name: string;
  public tasks: Realm.List<Task>;

  static schema = {
    name: "Project",
    primaryKey: "_id",
    properties: {
      _id: "int",
      name: "string",
      tasks: { type: "list", objectType: "Task" },
    },
  };
}

export class Task extends Realm.Object<Task> {
  public description: string;

  static schema = {
    name: "Task",
    embedded: true, // uncomment
    properties: {
      description: "string",
    },
  };
}

(async () => {
  let realm: any;

  try {
    realm = await Realm.open({
      inMemory: true,
      schema: [Project, Task],
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }

  try {
    realm.write(() => {
      const t1 = realm.create(Task, {
        description: "T1",
      });

      const t2 = realm.create(Task, {
        description: "T2",
      });

      realm.create(Project, {
        _id: 1,
        name: "P1",
        tasks: [t1, t2],
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(realm.objects(Project), null, 3));

  realm.close();
})();

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Please look at the console</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an important differentiation between a Realm Object and a Realm Embedded object:

A Realm object is a separate, independent object that is directly managed by Realm.

Whereas an Embedded Object is just that; embedded within a parent object. It is not a separate, independent object and is only managed by Realm through its parent object. Because of that, Embedded Objects cannot be directly written to Realm.

An embedded object does not exist without it's parent object. It cannot be stored in Realm directly; it has to be added to it's parent and then the parent must be stored (or it could be added to an already existing parent object).

Big picture is that Embedded Objects are actually part of the parent's schema and when the parent is deleted, so are it's embedded objects.

Additionally, Embedded Objects can only be queried *through* the parent object; so for example, suppose a Person object has an embedded Dog object. If you wanted to look for a person who has a dog named spot, it would be (pseudo code)

```
let somePerson = realm.query on the personObject.embeddedDog.name == "spot"
```

note that

> Embedded objects map to embedded documents in the parent type's
> schema . This behavior differs from regular Realm objects, which map
> to their own MongoDB collection.

so this

```
schema: [Project, Task],
```

won't work as a `Task` is part of the `Project`'s schema

**EDIT**

An example would be a business that has several addresses. The address themselves don't need to be separatly managed objects as they are directly tied to the parent business.

Here's a business object which will contain several embedded address objects

```
const BusinessSchema = {
  name: "Business",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
    _id: "objectId",
    name: "string",
    addresses: { type: "list", objectType: "Address" },//array of embedded objects
  },
};
```

and then the embedded address objects look like this

```
const AddressSchema = {
  name: "Address",
  embedded: true, // default: false
  properties: {
    street: "string?",
    city: "string?",
    country: "string?",
    postalCode: "string?",
  },
};
```

note that embedded objects must be set to `embedded: true` and then also insure the embedded object does not have a primary key.

Comment: If I take off Task from schema, I have this error :  "Exception in HostFunction: Schema validation failed due to the following errors: - Property 'Project.tasks' of type 'array' has unknown object type 'Task'" .     If fact, after reading your explanation and the doc more carefully, I realized I followed it to define objects but not to add them in the database. Please see next post.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think I will use embedded object in my project and I will manually implement cascade delete, which is a bit annoying because I have a 2 level one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Jay answer and after reading the doc more carefully, I changed the creation of Project and its embedded Tasks like this and it works :

```
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create("Project", {
    _id: 1,
    name: "P1",
    tasks: [
      {
        description: "T1",
      },
      {
        description: "T2",
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

But I am still unable to create embedded object when I model objects with class and constructor or class and static generate(). If you have a working example of this kind, please post it.

UPDATE (25/03/2023) : To be more explicit, how to modify the code below to make the embedded feature work ? But if possible, TASK being a class with a constructor.

Without the "embedded: true," line, the output of this code is:

> {"_id": "641e5fdebde518d4ac0e7665", "name": "P1", "tasks":
> [{"description": "T1"}, {"description": "T2"}]}

With the "embedded: true," the output of this code is:

> ERROR  Exception in HostFunction: Embedded objects cannot be created
> directly.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Realm from "realm";

export class Project extends Realm.Object<Project> {
  public _id: Realm.BSON.ObjectId;
  public name: string;
  public tasks: Realm.List<Task>;

  static schema = {
    name: "Project",
    primaryKey: "_id",
    properties: {
      _id: "objectId",
      name: "string",
      tasks: { type: "list", objectType: "Task" },
    },
  };

  constructor(realm: Realm, name: string, tasks: Task[] = []) {
    super(realm, {
      _id: new Realm.BSON.ObjectId(),
      name: name,
      tasks: tasks,
    });
  }
}

export class Task extends Realm.Object<Task> {
  public description: string;

  static schema = {
    name: "Task",
    embedded: true, // <==============================
    properties: {
      description: "string",
    },
  };

  constructor(realm: Realm, description: string) {
    super(realm, {
      description: description,
    });
  }
}

(async () => {
  let realm: any;

  try {
    realm = await Realm.open({
      inMemory: true,
      schema: [Project, Task],
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }

  try {
    realm.write(() => {
      new Project(realm, "P1", [new Task(realm, "T1"), new Task(realm, "T2")]);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }

  for (const item of realm.objects(Project)) {
    console.log(item.toJSON());
  }

  realm.close();
})();

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Please look at the console</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Embedded objects are incredibly versatile so I really suggest working toward using them! I updated my answer with some example code for a parent Business object which has embedded Addresses. For clarity, Embedded object are objects and and re-usable (see the Address object in my answer). The `tasks` here is a list (a map actually) of key: value pairs so it's not really akin to an embedded object. If it works, great! but it seems like having a re-usable Task object would be nifty!

Comment: I was able to use Embedded objects using schema but not when defining objects with a class which has a static schema and a constructor and whose objects can be added in the database just by creating instances of the class. I have not found any embedded example of this kind. And I do want to work this way. I think it's pretty cool.

Comment: You kinda lost me on that.... Realm objects should be defined as shown in my answer above. That's kinda the concept and how the SDK's work. Realm isolates the developer from some of the low level 'stuff'. It's there if you want it but creating Realm objects in code is a snap - even pre-populating them so they can be added with existing data. From a coding perspective, you're working with objects at a high level instead of digging into the console at a low level.

Comment: Please take a look at the update of my second post.

Comment: Right. Same issue. `Task` is not a managed object. Here (and maybe elsewhere) `schema: [Project, Task],` won't work because you're telling Realm there are two objects, Project and Task. There's only one Managed object, Project. Task is embedded within Project so when a project is loaded for example, it's task is with it. Doing this `schema: [Project, Task]` would be the same as this `schema: [Project, String]` and as you know Strings are not objects that are separately managed, they are 'part of' the parent object. Does that help?

Comment: Oh, and be careful about asking questions in an answer, others will flag it or downvote it - the additional example would be an excellent part of the original question.

Comment: Yes, It helped. What I wanted to do  is not supported by Realm.